# 'Failed to remove /Users/name/.cache' when building Solana program

Tags: solana-program, rust

I follow instructions in https://github.com/solana-labs/example-helloworld and got stuck in this step

`npm run build:program-rust`

The error shows

```
program-rust % npm run build:program-rust


> helloworld@0.0.1 build:program-rust
> cargo build-bpf --manifest-path=./src/program-rust/Cargo.toml --bpf-out-dir=dist/program

Warning: cargo-build-bpf is deprecated. Please, use cargo-build-sbf
cargo-build-bpf child: /Users/name/solana-release/bin/cargo-build-sbf --manifest-path=./src/program-rust/Cargo.toml --sbf-out-dir=dist/program --arch bpf
[2022-10-02T18:58:07.333175000Z ERROR cargo_build_sbf] Failed to remove /Users/name/.cache/solana/v1.29 while recovering from installation failure: No such file or directory (os error 2)
```

Solana version: solana-cli 1.14.3 (src:fa1e3263; feat:940802714)

My system: macOS Monterey 12.6

Any comments would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Use Solana 1.10. You have 1.11 installed